# SQL query to linq syntax

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, sql-to-linq-conversion

How can i convert this join stmnt to linq syntax

```
SELECT pv.Product_ID, pv.Product, v.Add_ID, v.Product_ID
  FROM Product AS pv 
  JOIN Product_Add AS v
  ON ((pv.Product_ID = v.Add_ID) OR (pv.Product_ID = v.Product_ID))
     where(( pv.Product_ID = v.Product_ID) OR (pv.product_ID = v.Add_ID))
```

Thanks

Comment: do accpet answer if you got the info you want

Answer (score 1):

I would convert this for you

but its better you use this tool which is really help full to me to convert sql to linq code

http://www.sqltolinq.com/

just download and install on your machine will do work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Join, you can use **from...where**, it's the same thing.

```
from pv in Product
from v in Product_Add
where ((pv.Product_ID == v.Add_ID) || (pv.Product_ID == v.Product_ID))
     &&(( pv.Product_ID = v.Product_ID) || (pv.product_ID = v.Add_ID))
```

(You just AND all the join conditions with the rest of the where if you have multiple joins)